# How to make a good procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

so I have just started to create procedure in pl/sql but my skills is very limited. I have this table:

```
bank_account ( 
  NUM_CC NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT PK_NUMCC PRIMARY KEY, 
  NUM_CLIENT NUMBER(10), 
  SOLD NUMBER(10)
)
```

I want to create a procedure to transfer an amount 'm' on my account, so i have write this procedure :

```
Create or replace procedure virement-cc(num-client number, num-cc number , m number)AS
Begin
  UPDATE bank_account
     SET SOLD = SOLD+m
   WHERE NUM_CLIENT = num-client 
     AND NUM_CC = num-cc ;
End ;
```

This is procedure is not good but i would like to know how to improve it to resolve my problem. Thank you all.

Comment: As a beginning, hyphens are not allowed in identifiers.

Comment: So `num_cc` identifies a bank account. Your procedure wants `num_client` and `num_cc`. What do you want to happen if this procedure gets called for a non-existing combination? `m` is a poor name for a variable by the way. Use something readable, like `amount` or `money_sent` or the like. And Littlefoot is right suggesting that you prefix parameters somehow to tell them from local variables and column names. Common prefixes are `p_` for "parameter" or `vi_`for "variable in" (because a procedure can also have out variables).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `in` parameters are not variable, so `vi_` makes no sense.

Comment: @William Robertson: You are right of course. I use this prefix anyway; v_, vi_, vo_, vio_ just look so consistent :-) I've also seen in_ and out_. What's important is that we have some naming convention to easily tell one thing from the other and have thus our code more readable and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 2):

- don't use hyphen but underline
- don't name parameters as columns; prefix them with e.g. `p_`. Otherwise, Oracle will simply do *nothing* (but set column's name to its current value) and you'd have impression that *nothing happened*

So:

```
Create or replace procedure virement_cc
  (p_num_client number, p_num_cc number, p_m number)
AS
Begin
  UPDATE bank_account
    SET SOLD = SOLD + p_m
  WHERE NUM_CLIENT = p_num_client 
    AND NUM_CC = p_num_cc;
End ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between 'num_cc' the input parameter and 'num_cc' the column name.  Rename 'num_cc' the input parameter as 'p_num_cc'.

Your WHERE clause has an issue:

```
WHERE NUM_CLIENT = p_num_client 
     AND NUM_CC = p_num_cc ;
```

(I've gone ahead and renamed your input parameter)

If NUM_CC is the primary key (it is) then it *uniquely* identifies a particular role, so there is no need to include a comparison on num_client.  And with that you don't even need an input parameter for it.

Give more thought to your naming conventions

1. I name all of my table columns in the format 'adjective_noun'.  And don't be afraid to be descriptive.  Instead of NUM_CC, how about CARD_NUMBER.  Instead of NUM_CLIENT, try CLIENT_NUMBER.  This 'adjective_noun' format also has the advantage of absolutely eliminating the possibility of accidentally trying to use a reserved or key word.
2. I name all of my parameters P_'adjective_noun'
3. I name all of my internal variables V_'adjective_noun'.

You may well decide on different naming standards.  They key is to actually *have* naming standards, and that those standards be well thought out an reasoned.